# Корректные модальные окна для мобилок

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите плагин модального окна для мобильных устройств на js, который:

1. Легко кастомизируеются css свойства
2. Документ не прокручивается при прокрутке внутри модального окна
3. При открытии модального окна, основной документ не прокручивается к началу.

Или как реализовать сие чудо.

Пробую стандартными способами, но ios возникает проблема с прокруткой, скроллится документ. Если сделать для `body {position: fixed;}` то при появлении окна происходит прокрутка к началу документа

Comment: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ ни разу косяков не было

Comment: на js, без jquery